# bq load command to load parquet file from GCS to BigQuery with column name start with number

Tags: google-bigquery

I am loading parquet file into BigQuery using bq load command, my parquet file contains column name start with number (e.g. 00_abc, 01_xyz). since BigQuery don't support column name start number I have created column in BigQuery such as _00_abc, _01_xyz.
But I am unable to load the parquet file to BigQuery using bq load command.

Is there any way to specify bq load command that source column 00_abc (from parquet file) will load to target column _00_abc (in BigQuery).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gouranga Basak

Answer (score 2):

It's general best practice to not start a Parquet column name with a number. You will experience compatibility issues with more than just `bq load`. For example, many Parquet readers use the [`parquet-avro` library](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-avro), and [Avro's documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) says:

> The name portion of a fullname, record field names, and enum symbols must:
>
> - start with `[A-Za-z_]`
> - subsequently contain only `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

The solution here is to rename the column in the Parquet file. Depending on how much control you have over the Parquet file's creation, you may need to write a Cloud Function to rename the columns (Pandas Dataframes won't complain about your column names).

Comment: Hello Ben, 
Thank you for your answer but for some reason we will not be able to modify the schema of source parquet file.
I was looking for a solution, if there is any option in “bq load” command which can load column "a" from parquet file into column "b" in BigQuery (e.g., source column to target column mapping).
If there is no option, then probably we need to generate new parquet file from source parquet file or use other alternate option to load data into BigQuery.